# Why does the model give probability close to 1 for negative examples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

This is not what I had expected!

I have trained a CNN on [SVHN](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/). The accuracy is close to ~0.93 and overall it works really well when tested on the single number images. So if I test the model with images that contain a single number such as follows:

[image]

it works great with the expected class probability close to `1`. But if I supply the model with random images like some `house` or a `lion` , it will still predict a class with a probability close to 1. I cannot understand the reason for this. It should have predicted very low probabilities for each class.

Here is how I created the network.

```
     import tensorflow.keras as keras

     model = keras.Sequential()

    # First Conv Layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 96, kernel_size = (11,11), strides = (4,4), padding = "same", input_shape=(227,227,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3,3), strides = (2,2), padding="same"))


    # .. More Convolution Layer ... 

    # .. SOME Fully Connected Layers ..

    # Final Fully Connected Layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))

    model.add(keras.layers.Activation("softmax"))

    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])


    data_generator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

    train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
            'train',
            target_size=(227, 227),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            color_mode='rgb',
            class_mode='categorical'
    )

    model.fit_generator(
        train_generator
        epochs = 12, 
        steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(num_train_samples / batch_size), 
        verbose = 2
    )
```

As could also be seen from the code I have shared above, I have used:

- Loss function as `categorical_crossentropy`
- Final layer activation function as `softmax`

There are 10 classes 0 to 9. Would I also need to have a 11th class that has some random images? But that sounds very weird. Did I choose the incorrect loss / activation functions?

Comment: You should tune down your expectations, the model has never seen anything other than digits, so it won't work for negative examples. A Bayesian model might work better.

Comment: Image recognition begins from the premise that the image you're showing it is something that it can recognize.

Comment: @TheLoneDeranger Sure. But I would never expect the probabilities close to 1 for negative examples even if the model has not seen the example.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to train your network with images of the numbers and to include some random other images (of houses or lions) and label them all as "not numbers". A convolutional neural network does not look at your entire image at once, but bits of it at a time. It can easily find sub shapes that resemble numbers too.

Your loss and activation is fine.

Comment: But it does not sound convincing, considering the network gives a probability of `1` on random images. A low probability would have given much assurance on the state of model.

Comment: Does it continuously predict the same class with high probability? You will need some offset to allow the model to predict something that is not a digit.

Comment: What you are asking about (the fact that the probability is high) might simply be regarding your conv layers with large (11) kernel sizes and large strides (4). I would suggest keeping kernel at 3 and strides at 1. Max pooling pool size 2 and stride 2.

Comment: Yes. It continuously predicts the same class with high probability. I am training with 11th class that contains images from CIFAR dataset. Let me see if that helps. But still, should not the model give low probability for something that is not a digit? Is there some other reason you could think of?

Comment: If it is predicting the same class with probability 1 then your model is overfitted. Look at my suggestions above regarding the conv layers and ensure that your digit classes are of similar size.

Comment: All classes are of same size 32x32. I tried containing random images from CIFAR as a 11th class but the network is not learning.

Comment: Size of classes meaning: 500 images of 1's, 500 images of 2's, 500 images of 3's,  etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192143/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-timmertak).